# Issue with Azure Blob Indexer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I have come across a scenario where I want to index all the files that are present in the blob storage.
But, In a scenario if the file that is uploaded in Blob is password protected, the indexer fails and also the indexer is now not able to index the remaining files.

```
[
    {
        "key": null,
        "errorMessage": "Error processing blob 'url' with content type ''. Status:422, error: "
    }
]
```

Is there a way to ignore the password protected files or a way to continue with the indexing process even if there is an error in some file.

Comment: Can you share your indexer definition?

Comment: `   Indexer indexer = new Indexer()
            {
                Name = indexerName,
                DataSourceName = name,
                TargetIndexName = indexName,
                Schedule = new IndexingSchedule()
                {
                    Interval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["indexrefreshtime"]))
                }
            };`

Comment: indexer.Parameters = new IndexingParameters().ExcludeFileNameExtensions(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filetoignore"].Split(','));
            indexer.FieldMappings = new List<FieldMapping>();
            indexer.FieldMappings.Add(new Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.FieldMapping()
            {
                SourceFieldName = "metadata_storage_path",
                MappingFunction = Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.FieldMappingFunction.Base64Encode()

            });

Comment: Please do not include these in comments. Instead edit your question and include the code there.

Comment: I guess the problem is the file that is uploaded is password protected and hence the indexer is failing but it doesnt continues with the indexing of other files

Answer (score 2):

See **Dealing with unsupported content types** section in [Controlling which blobs are indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#controlling-which-blobs-are-indexed). Use `failOnUnsupportedContentType` configuration setting:

```
PUT https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/[indexer name]?api-version=2016-09-01
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: [admin key]

{
  ... other parts of indexer definition
  "parameters" : { "configuration" : { "failOnUnsupportedContentType" : false } }
}
```

Comment: I did set the parameter like this, but doesn't seem to be working.
 indexer.Parameters = new IndexingParameters().DoNotFailOnUnsupportedContentType();

is there anything more that i need to do ?

Comment: What is your search service name and indexer name? I can take a look at your indexer definition to make sure it was actually updated.

Comment: I am not sure if I should share those details.
I am using the .NET client code to create the indexer


      indexer.Parameters = new IndexingParameters().DoNotFailOnUnsupportedContentType();
            // excluding files from indexing
            indexer.Parameters = new IndexingParameters().ExcludeFileNameExtensions(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filetoignore"].Split(','));
            indexer.FieldMappings = new List<FieldMapping>();

Comment: But are you making the call to update your indexer definition? You can email the details to me instead of posting here: eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain.

Comment: my code basically deletes the existing indexer and then creates a new one.

Comment: We can't help you unless we know your service name and indexer name.

Comment: setting the parameters like this , would work?

indexer.Parameters = new IndexingParameters().ExcludeFileNameExtensions(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filetoignore"].Split(',')).DoNotFailOnUnsupportedContentType();

Comment: I guess the problem is the file that is uploaded is password protected and hence the indexer is failing but it doesnt continues with the indexing of other files

Comment: Eugene works for Microsoft in Azure Search team. He would be the best person to help you out with this. He has shared his email address in one of the comments above. Please email him the details he has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ignore the password protected files or a way to
>   continue with the indexing process even if there is an error in some
>   file.

One possible way to do it is define a metadata on the blob by the name `AzureSearch_Skip` and set its value to `true`. In this case, Azure Search Service will ignore this blob and moves to the next blob in the list.

You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#controlling-which-parts-of-the-blob-are-indexed.

Comment: This is a good approach if you want to ignore one or a few known bad blobs. To deal with all blobs, using `failOnUnsupportedContentType` configuration setting is better.